Icons and translations not loading in Flutter Web
I'm building a Flutter web app, but for some reason the icons (via the font_awesome_flutter) and translations (via the easy_localizations package) aren't loading on the iPhone:

And this is how it should look:

On other platforms this web app works fine, but on iPhone there are some issues. What could be wrong?

try to build with this command: flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --no-tree-shake-icons

@Aks, It didn't work(

In my project i have faced this problem. remove unusefull library and check it i think that is solution.
